# how to deploy github project to aws without CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

in my region, there is no **AWS codepipeline** available

and I need a method to deploy my GitHub project to **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**

is there any suggestion??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is not CP, then maybe there is CodeBuild (CB) and you can use this. CB's [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/create-project-console.html#create-project-console-source) can be github.

Subsequently, in your `buildspec.yml` you would use EB CLI or AWS CLI to "manually" deploy your application to your EB environment.